# In org-mode, how do I set it so that my searches (C-c a s) do not return DONE or CANCELED entries?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I set it so that my searches (<kbd>C-c a s</kbd>) do not return DONE or CANCELED entries? I am aware that I can archive the DONE or CANCELED entries, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: You can add your specific search to `org-agenda-custom-commands`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your search query to be:

```
-{DONE\|CANCELLED} <rest of query here>
or
-DONE -CANCELLED <rest of query>
```

And it will by default remove your done and cancelled tasks.

If you are always looking for a specific string you can create a `org-agenda-custom-command` (See [Storing Searches](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Storing-searches)).  It would have to look something like:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("t" "Test Search" search "-{DONE\\|CANCELLED} +<query>")))
```